# How to achieve multiple content sections in one Jekyll layout file?

Tags: html, ruby, yaml, jekyll

I'm working on a layout file that has uses tabs as  the navigation bar and there needs to be 3 sections of content to match the 3 tabs of the menu. How can I  label multiple content sections in my *.markdown file and then include those sections in different places in my layout?

For context, my code looks similar to the below and the content I'm looking to reference includes markdown styling, so I'm hoping to not have to translate that into HTML in order to front load it thru YAML. I'm very new to Jekyll however, so I'm not sure what's possible

```
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-view" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-view-tab">
    <div>
       [Some unrelated in-file HTML]
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-compare" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-compare-tab">
    <div>
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-glossary" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-glossary-tab">
    <div>
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```